# How to access array in function outside of main?

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a program that prints out a store inventory. I print out the variables from my objects in the getInventory function. However, when I try and print out the entire inventory in the getStore function it returns nothing. I feel like it is an issue with my pointer properly pointing to my array but I am not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Weapon
{
private:
    std::string nameWeapon, messageUsed;
    bool ownedWeapon;
    double weaponCost;
    int numberUses;

public:
    //Default constructor
    Weapon() 
    {
        nameWeapon = "weapon name";
        messageUsed = "weapon sound";
        weaponCost = 0;
        ownedWeapon = false;
        numberUses = 1;
    }
    //Non-Default Constructor
    Weapon(std::string nW, std::string mU,double wC,bool oW, int nU )
    {
        nameWeapon = nW;
        messageUsed = mU;
        weaponCost = wC;
        ownedWeapon = oW;
        numberUses = nU;
    }
    void getInventory()
    {
        std::cout << nameWeapon << "\t" << messageUsed << "\t" << weaponCost << "\t" << ownedWeapon << "\t" << numberUses << "\n";
    }
    void getStore(Weapon* weaponArray)
    {
        std::cout << "Name" << "\t" << "Sound" << "\t" << "Price" << "\t" << "Owned";
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
              weaponArray[i].getInventory();
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    Weapon weaponArray[9]{};
    weaponArray[0] = Weapon("Broad Sword","Clang!",50,false,3);
    weaponArray[1] = Weapon("Champions Sword","Swoosh!",99.99,false,5);
    weaponArray[2] = Weapon("Dagger","Ding!",12.25,false,1);
    weaponArray[3] = Weapon("Poisin Dagger","Shh",18.50,false,1);
    weaponArray[4] = Weapon("Sturdy Dagger","Gronk!",14.75,false,3);
    weaponArray[5] = Weapon("Short Bow","T'wang!",35.75,false,3);
    weaponArray[6] = Weapon("Champions Bow","Swoop!",90.15,false,5);
    weaponArray[7] = Weapon("Champions Axe","Bash!",110.11,false,6);
    weaponArray[8] = Weapon("Throwing Axe","Bonk!",25.75,false,2);

    void getStore();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may find [List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) helpful. It eliminates the need for individually assigning all of the array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getStore();
```

This is a function stub. It declares a function `getStore` that takes no arguments and returns nothing to be implemented later. This is almost definitely a typo.

Further, because `void getStore(Weapon* weaponArray)` is in the Weapon class, you have to call it on a weapon, which doesn't look right. You probably mean to do this:

```
class Weapon {
    // ...
};

void getStore(Weapon* weaponArray, unsigned sz)
{
    std::cout << "Name" << "\t" << "Sound" << "\t" << "Price" << "\t" << "Owned";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
          weaponArray[i].getInventory();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Weapon weaponArray[9]{};
    weaponArray[0] = Weapon("Broad Sword","Clang!",50,false,3);
    //...

    getStore(weaponArray, 9);
}
```